# Ionic 3 subscribe fires multiple times

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3

I'm struggling with this code from an Ionic taxi app for a few weeks. My problem is:

When the page loads, the subscription is fired several times along with the other functions within it. The same happens when some travel information is modified in Firebase

Is it possible to load travel and driver information only once so that the screen is just monitoring the other services?

Traveling.ts:

```
export class TravelingPage {

  driver;
  trip;
...

constructor(
        public nav: NavController,
        ...
      ) {
        ...
        if (this.navParams.get('tripId')) {
          this.tripId = this.navParams.get('tripId')
        }
        else {
          this.tripId = this.tripService.getId();
        }

      }

        ionViewDidLoad() {

        this.tripService.getTrip(this.tripId).take(1).subscribe(snapTrip => {
          this.driverService.getDriver(snapTrip.driverId).take(1).subscribe(snapDriver => {

              // load trip data
              this.trip = snapTrip;

              // load driver data
              this.driver = snapDriver;

              // watchTrip
              this.watchTrip(this.trip.id);

              // start map
              this.loadMap();

              // check if trip is already paid
              if (!this.trip['paymentData'] && this.orderStatus == false) {
                // pay Trip
                this.tripService.doOrder(this.trip);
              } else {
                console.info('Paid already. Do nothing');
              }
            }
          });
        })

      }
...
}
```

TripService.ts:

```
getTrip(id) {
    return this.db.object('trips/' + id);
  }
```

Comment: try to create one function and add the logic of ionViewDidLoad in this function. call this function from the constructor.

Comment: Thanks @kevalnayak ! The problem continues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. Was an duplicated Firebase node status

Comment: can you please describe more in your ans?

Answer (score 1):

When using subscription you should always unsubscribe it in order to prevent multiple subscription. You can try assigning the subscription on a variable and on the ionViewWillLeave() unsubscribe it

Comment: Hi @Keeno thanks for help. I received this tip from VSCode: "Property 'unsubscribe' does not exist in type 'FirebaseObjectObservable <any>'. Did you mean 'subscribe'?"